# Maven works but eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I created a maven project from the command-line interface. Configured the dependencies with my other maven projects. Now when I run my project, it works without any problem using the following maven command:

```
$ mvn clean
$ mvn install
$ mvn exec:java

Hello world!
```

Then, I use the following maven command to have my eclipse project files.

```
$ mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I go and open my project using Eclipse Kepler, however as you can see there is a exclamation point on my project and it does not run from eclipse.

[image]

The problem is I do not know how to find the *error* on eclipse..

Comment: It appears from the icon that eclipse is not recognizing this as a maven project (missing the little m). Have you tried right-clicking, going to Configure, and "Convert to Maven project"?

Comment: @GregWhitaker it did not solve the issue, there is now a little M along with the exclamation point though.

Comment: @SargeBorsch not sure? how to check and if not how to install?

Comment: You are not seeing any errors in the Problems tab?  The red exclamation point usually means there is a problem with your build path and you should be able to see those errors in the Problems tab.

Comment: @celebisait in upper menu "Help" maybe. Didn't remember.